# Spring Security OAuth2 server side, how to require client_id and client_secret on all request

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am integrating with Spring Security OAuth2 and I am stuck on trying to require the client_id and client_secret for every request. So I'd like all my requests to require access_token, client_id and client_secret, is that doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything is possible. I'm not sure why you'd want to do that (and you really ought not to use request parameters or body for secrets), but all you would need is to add a custom filter that grabs the client details and asserts on them. Something like a `BasicAuthenticationFilter`, for instance.

Comment: I see, thanks. Why shouldn't I use the parameter or body for secrets? not even if I use https?

Comment: Preferably not. They are much more likely to be logged and revealed in an uncontrolled way.

Comment: I am really confused, how we are supposed to send the secret to the server to authenticate then?

Comment: A resource server is not responsible for authenticating a client - it trusts what it finds in the access token. The authorization server has to authenticate clients (normally via HTTP Basic - i.e. in a request header).

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying now. That makes perfect sense. So how should I implement my use case where I want to limit access to a handful of clients, but the resources themselves are not protected, i.e. they don't belong to a resource owner.

Comment: There has to be a resource owner, otherwise you can't protect them, so I'm confused. How would you "limit access" without a protected resource? Maybe the resource owner in your case *is* the client (not the user)?